# WordPress. how to use wp_enqueue_script to dynamic code script or style

Tags: php, wordpress

Create a block of code dynamically, where the content uses a variable.

The `hpcs` reports that I need to use `wp_enqueue_script`, it was understood that it is used to import a file, but since the content of the block is not dynamic, what is the best way to implement it?

code example:

```
$html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            (function() { $MTS.openChk({ url: "' . esc_url( $url ) . '", mode: "automatic" }); })();
          </script>';
```

**Error-**

```
Scripts must be registered/enqueued via wp_enqueue_script
```

Comment: What is the url value? What is $MTS? More complete information is needed

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani the $url is dynamic, sometimes it can be www.site1.com another can be www.site2.com etc...
So it prevents me from turning it into a static file and importing it with wp_enqueued

Comment: Disappointing that there doesn't appear to be an answer to this. I have a script dynamically generated by a shortcode, and WP won't let me turn off wpautop (the official way of disabling it does absolutely nothing), so the only way I could prevent <p> tags being needlessly inserted around my script tag would be to enqueue it. But of course there's no way to do that, because, dynamically generated from shortcode parameters.